# Finding Screen Dimensions Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have read a few posts on this site about finding screen dimensions and most of them reference `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay;`

I tried to this is my code and got an error saying `cannot resolve method getWindowManager()`. My code is below so you can fully understand:

```
public class MainActivity {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay;
    //WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    //int displayid = Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY;
    //Display display = DisplayManager.getDisplay(displayid);
    int tlx = (168/800)*display.getWidth();
    int tly = (136/480)*display.getHeight();
    int brx = (631/800)*display.getWidth();
    int bry = (343/480)*display.getHeight();

    int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

This is just an excerpt in case somethings don't make sense. Also, I'm using the display dimensions to find screen elements within an application. If I should be using the window dimensions for this please inform me upon how to go about doing that as well, but I still need to get the display right so I can use methods such as the .getRotation() one shown above. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference `getWindowManager` from an Activity. Your `MainActivity` doesn't appear to be extending `Activity` so you either need to extend `Actvity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

Or pass an activity to that class then do something like this.

```
Display display = myActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
```

Or through a Context

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
```

Comment: I extended activity in my MainActivity and am now getting the error "Non-static method getWindowManager cannot be reference from a static context. I have also gotten this error in a few other places; how should I remedy this.

Comment: Main should not be static. Also where is your onCreate, onResume  and other Activity methods?

Comment: I'm making this to run specific shell commands based on other events, kind of like a macro. So I thought to flesh out the conditional actions I wanted to preform before placing those actions in the specific Activity methods. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: Not necessarily, but you can't access Activity specific objects. If this is just for testing you should create your own value for Display.

Comment: I placed the given code in onStop(){} to simulate the application running in the background. I got an error when I tried to throw IOException. The exception came from this line:

Comment: Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

the error said onStop() in [package name] clashes with onStop() in android.app.Activity, overridden method does not throw java.io.IOException

Comment: You are extending a class then creating a method that the parent class has without overriding it. Call your test test onStop() something else like onStopTest()

Comment: I used a try-catch to fix it, is this correct? I am no longer in testing and am implementing these items in the final application in the onStop(){} method.

Comment: try/catch blocks should be used as error handling not masking. If you are in fact using it as a way to handle errors and not just "skip" them then yes, you are doing it right. I can't say for sure if you are doing your onStop() right without seeing your code. However, if the program behaves as expected then yes I would say you are doing it correctly.